# Somehow my deployment was gone, is there any place which tracked the ‘gone/delete’ operation?

Tags: kubernetes

I deployed a deployment `nginx` in Kubernetes cluster as below.
The deployments shows as below:

```
[root@iZwz97twzbvh62zh76pk8zZ zzx]# k get deployment nginx
NAME    DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
nginx   2         2         2            1           7s
```

The deployment template is as below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 2 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.17.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Somehow the deployment `nginx` was gone, I wonder whether there is any place which tracked the ‘gone/delete’ operation?

Comment: no, by default all expired state is purged by etcd every 5 minutes. You need another system gathering kubelet output from stdout or journald (e.g. elasticsearch) or a backup of etcd to be able to see it. If you ssh to the node, you might still see some information from journald.

Answer (score 1):

There has to be another audit log, related to the user operation that trigger initially 'delete deployment' action on your Kubernetes cluster.

The audit log you pasted is only a part of this delete operation chain, coming from system component: kubelet, responsible for deleting Pods -> ReplicaSet belonging to your Deployment resource.

So look for audit log containing this piece of information:

```
  authorizationInfo: [
   0: {
    granted:  true     
    permission:  "io.k8s.extensions.v1beta1.deployments.delete"
    resource:  "extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/nginx"     
   }
 ]
```